# libpcap with python and C fails "undefined reference to pcap_parse"

Tags: python, c, libpcap

This is a bit of a two pronged question. 
Using Ubuntu 11.04, and Python 2.7

My problem started when I was trying to compile a C program to capture and decode IP packets.
When compiling, I get this error
$ gcc -lpcap decode_sniff.c
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so: undefined reference to `pcap_parse'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I confirmed and re-confirmed that libnet1-dev and libpcap-dev are installed (using apt-get).

Eventually I gave up on the C program and went to work with Python instead. I installed and built the pypcap package (http://pycap.sourceforge.net/). However, when trying to import the pypcap module, I get ;

Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pycap.capture
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1: undefined symbol: pcap_parse

Clearly I am missing a common file or package or module or something.
I've googled this for a while now and haven't gotten anywhere.
Does anyone have some insight for me?

Comment: what is the program (and its version) you're trying to compile? also, what is the version of libpcap you got?

Comment: libpcap 1.1.1-2. The program is something I wrote from a tutorial in a book.captures packets, and breaks down / prints the various layers. They python side of my problem crashes with the same error just when trying to import the module

Comment: try installing libpcap0.8-dev i've seen threads where it was the solution to a similar problem. (if it solves the problem, tell me and i'll put this as an answer, so you can accept it)

Comment: according to Synaptic, libpcap-dev (ver 1.1.1-2) and libpcap0.8-dev (ver 1.1.1-2) are installed. Honestly don't understand the difference in naming, yet the same version numbering.